# copy a struct from src to dst

Tags: c, struct

I really need help doing this function, I am trying to copy a card structure from src to dst. I attempted to do something but i think its wrong. I am really confused. Please help me.

```
struct card
{
   enum Value val;
   enum Suit suit;
}
```

I have a function which I cannot change:

```
void copy_card(struct card *dst, struct card *src)
{
   /* Copy a card structure from src to dst */

   for(i = 0; i <sizeof(struct); i++){

       dst[i] = src[i];
   }
}
```

Comment: See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html

Comment: @MartinBeckett The OP just wants to copy one structure - `memcpy` is not necessary here.

Comment: What do you mean by "a function which I cannot change"?  Is it the signature that can't be changed (which isn't a problem) or the content that can't be changed (in which case the whole thing is completely broken).  You should be careful when defining your problem.  It is important to include information about things that can't be changed, but it is also important to be clear about what can't be changed.

Comment: `struct` s can be copied with simple assignment here `*dst=*src` would do the trick but remember the difference between a deep copy and shallow copy , its very necessary when you are using pointers inside your structures.

Comment: Strongly suggest throwing that function into the bit bucket.  Then where ever it was being called replace the call with `memcpy( &dest, &src, sizeof( struct card ) );`

Comment: To further expand why your code was segfault-ing:

the [n] operator takes into account the size of the data type. So if you do `(int*)[1] it takes the int* + sizeof(int) * 1`

Answer (score 3):

```
void copy_card(struct card *dst, struct card *src) {
    *dst = *src;
}
```

This uses a straight-forward structure assignment to copy the data at the memory address of `src` to the location of `dst`, assuming that both pointers have been properly initialized.

Comment: I think the intent was more to explain that a `struct` provides a *copy constructor* allowing structures to be assigned with all static values copied from `src` to `dest`... and that in the example `struct card *dst` is presumed to be the address of a single `struct` and not a pointer to an array of struct. Something to explain why you are able to do `*src = *dst` in that case.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin there are no "copy constructor" in C .  Structs can be copied by value just like any other data type

Comment: Perhaps the term *shallow copy* would have been a better choice than *copy constructor*, in order to emphasize the C/C++ distinction, but I seriously doubt there was any confusion imparted by the use of one instead of the other.